# calling winrs multiple times from TeamCity

Tags: command-line, teamcity, winrm, winrs

if I run 2 winrs commands in the same Team City Command Line like this:

[image: Failing Build]

The build will hang.

[image: Hanging Build]

- if I manually kill the winrs process on the build agent, the build will finish but will exit with code 1.
- if I run just one winrs command the build will pass.
- If I split the winrs command into 2 different build steps the build will also pass.
- If i put the two lines in a batch file and run that on the build agent it works also.
- If i Put the two lines in a cmd file and run that on the build agent as the build agent user it works also.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here/how to fix this?

I'm hoping either a Team City or winrs guru can help me.

Comment: Would you mind making an experiment? Put these two lines into *.cmd file and try to execute it on the agent (using same user account as the agent)

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov I'll give it a go and get back to you asap.

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov I tried runnign the cmd file as the "TeamCity" user and it works fine.. just like running the batch file. I tried running the cmd file from Team City and it hangs (See picture). Weird hey?

Comment: so it hangs after second command? Right where is should have finished?

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov yep.. every time..

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem with Jenkins instead of TeamCity

Answer (score 3):

Prefix your commands with START /WAIT

Answer (score 0):

yes, START /WAIT works, even with winrs requests to multiple servers in the same build step
it won't return the output though

Comment: Hey.. best thing todo is to up vote @Jon-Canning's answer then add your answer as a comment.